# How to convert two rows into one row as precedent record and current record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table has following data in it.

```
Batch      Ingredient       Transaction date
----   -----------------  --------------------
A              I1              2019/05/22
A              I2              2019/05/23
A              I3              2019/05/24
```

I would like to show only the most two records by transaction date in the following format

```
Batch      Ingredient1     TransDate1    Ingredient2     TransacDate2
----    ---------------- ------------- ---------------- --------------    
A              I3          2019/05/24        I2           2019/05/23
```

The ingredient1 should be the most recent record and the ingredient is the one before ingredient. No ingredient3.

I tried the pivot table, but not work.

Comment: Add some Batch B rows too. And adjust the result - if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select batch,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then ingredient end) as ingredient1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then transdate end) as transdate1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then ingredient end) as ingredient2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then transdate end) as transdate2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by batch order by transdate desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
group by batch;
```